# Truffle development error "Greeter has no network configuration for its current network id"

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I am in the truffle development console and when I type "Greeter.address" I get an error that says "Error: Greeter has no network configuration for its current network id".[picture of error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZF4c.png) However, in my truffle-config.js, I have it set so that the network id matches. [picture of truffle-config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdAU9.png). Also, the migration did work.

Comment: Did you restart ganache after initial deployment?

Comment: @Ismael I actually didn't use ganache to deploy the smart contract

Comment: @Ismael I restarted it thank you for the help

Comment: @ Ismael hi I am having the same issue again on another project however I restarted ganache and I still got the same error

Comment: Every time you restart ganache it will launch with a new network id, and start with a fresh blockchain. If you want to reuse an address make sure to launch ganache with a persisten id and blockchain.

Comment: @Ismael to restart ganache would I need to just close out of the application completely to restart it or is there a certain command I need to type in the terminal?

Comment: You have shared very little information, so my advice is general and perhaps not the best to your situation in particular. If you restart ganache you will have to redeploy your contracts. In the worst case you can remove build/ directory, compile all contracts and redeploy.

Comment: @Ismael I tried to redeploy them and I get an error that says: Error deployment failed, "ObsToken" --invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 1 expected 0!  my 2_deploy_contract.js  code is : `// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
var ObsToken = artifacts.require('./ObsToken.sol')

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ObsToken).then(function () {
    return deployer.deploy(ObsToken, ObsToken.address)
  })
}
`

Comment: That is a different error messages. I suggest to search for similar error messages on ethereum.stackexchange.com, if you cannot find something that works for you, then create a new question.

Comment: @Ismael ok thank you for help